# Preload and Resize image jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my actual Javascript, i preload some images and display them on the body of my index.html. I need a way to resize them in order to fot the width and height of the window. Here is my actual code:

```
function($) {
    $.preLoadImages = function() {
        var args_len = arguments.length;
        for (var i = args_len; i--; ) {
            var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
            cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
            arrayimg.push(cacheImage);
        }
        arrayimg.reverse();
    }
})(jQuery)

function resizing(img) {

    var $image = img;
    var image_width = $image.width;
    var image_height = $image.height;
    var body_width = $("#corps").width();
    var body_height = $("#corps").height();
    $image.width = body_width;
    $image.height = body_height;

}

$.preLoadImages("./images/01.jpg", "./images/02.jpg", "./images/03.jpg", "./images/p1.jpg", "./images/p2.jpg", "./images/p3.jpg");
for ( j = 0; j < arrayimg.length; j++) {
    resizing(arrayimg[j]);
}
```

This code actually works pretty well. The main problem is that the resize  is not keeping the aspect of the actual picture. I need some code that respect the aspect ratio of the initial picture.

Comment: Do you need to resize the images in javascript? Could it be done in CSS? you could keep the aspect ratio easily this way.

Comment: Well, to be honnest, i need to preload my pictures into my javascript so i dont know how you can easily resize them with CSS without a <img> in the html for example.

Comment: In the function "resizing", you store the "image_width" and "image_height", but never use it. Obviously you can get the ratio from these two variables. And Regarding to your requirement, fit to the height or width, and adjust the other variable with the calculated ratio.

Comment: If you have the CSS in the CSS file before the images are added to the DOM it will still take effect when they are injected. You could also add CSS attributes through jQuery but I don't think this would be needed.

Comment: how will you do that with css @StuartMiller ?

Comment: Are you appending the images to the #corps div and want them to match the width of it and be the correct height based on aspect ratio? If so, set the image width to be 100% of it's parent #corps

Comment: ok i got it . I didnt know that you can actually manipulate preload images with css. Thanks a lot @StuartMiller

Comment: Your welcome, your not really manipulating preloaded images more just setting the CSS and when images are added top the DOM they get the rules applied to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the ratio like this:

```
var ratio = Math.min(body_width/image_width, body_height/image_height);
```

Then just multiply:

```
$image.width = ratio*body_width;
$image.height = ratio*body_height;
```

I assumed you want to "fit" the image inside the body. If you want to clip, replace `Math.min` with `Math.max` (and add overflow:hidden etc...)

Comment: @W.H. You should only do this once, because the calculations gets distorted when you change the width/height attributes. Save them as data attributes if you need to do multiple calculations.

Comment: ok i get it now David. Thanks for the help along with @StuartMiller.